# Extracting columns from Fasta file in Linux

Tags: linux, text-formatting, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file which looks like this

```
>ENST00000632684.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:7:142786213:142786224:1 gene:ENSG00000282431.1 gene_biotype:TR_D_gene transcript_biotype:TR_D_gene gene_symbol:TRBD1 description:T cell receptor beta diversity 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12158]
GGGACAGGGGGC
>ENST00000434970.2 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:22439007:22439015:1 gene:ENSG00000237235.2 gene_biotype:TR_D_gene transcript_biotype:TR_D_gene gene_symbol:TRDD2 description:T cell receptor delta diversity 2 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12255]
CCTTCCTAC
```

I want to extract the gene_symbol and description. But unfortunately the description has spaces in between and I am not able to extract the complete description.

I have tried this

```
cat Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.cdna.all.fa | grep ">" | cut -f 7,8 -d" "  > Human_Annotations
```

but this gives me an output like this, where the description is broken.

```
gene_symbol:TRBD1 description:T
gene_symbol:TRDD2 description:T
```

I want output like this

```
TRBD1 T cell receptor beta diversity 1
TRDD2 T cell receptor delta diversity 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
cat ... | sed -n '/^>/ { s/.*description: *//; s/\[.*//; p; }'
```

(Untested as I’m on mobile.)

There are more elegant ways; for instance an Awk loop would be most flexible.

Comment: This works but `cat` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F ':' '/^>/ { sub(" .*",    "", $10)
                   sub(" \\[.*", "", $11)
                   print $10, $11 }' file.fa
```

The data that you'd like to extract is the first word in the 10th field and everything up to the `[` in the 11th field of each header line, if the fields are `:`-separated.

The code strips everything off from the first space in the 10th field, and everything after the `[` in the 11th field (including the `[` and the preceding space).

The modified 10th and 11th fields are then printed.

The output given the data in the question:

```
TRBD1 T cell receptor beta diversity 1
TRDD2 T cell receptor delta diversity 2
```